# How to separate Toolbox and Tool Options from the other Docks?

Tags: gimp

So, I had accidentally closed the Toolbox Dock and went into Single Window mode.  I then went to `Window > Recently Closed Docks` and reopened the Toolbox Dock.  This resulted in the Toolbox Dock to appear separately from the single window.  From there I left the Single Window mode and it joined the two Docks together and I can no longer separate them.

[image]

As the Toolbox doesn't have a tab associated with it, I **can't** close all of the the tabs on the right.  I guess could close the each separate tab on the left side recreate the Dock manually, but that is a lot of tabs and is really annoying. I could even reset the UI to defaults through `Edit > Preferences > Interface > Window Management > Reset Saved Window Positions to Default Values`, but this seems a bit overkill.  Is there a way to separate these two halves from each other in some other way?

Using GIMP 2.10.8.

Comment: Resetting docks to their default positions is done using `Edit > Preferences > Interface > Window Management > Reset Saved Window Positions to Default Values`.

Comment: @mvanle ah, you're right. I'll fix. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Windows positions and docks are defined in the `sessionrc` file in the Gimp profile, which is  a text file that can be edited with a regular text editor.

#### PSA: This is done by a trained professional, imitate at your own risk

You can possibly start a new dock with a dialog you don't use (for instance, `Buffers`) close Gimp, edit the `sessionrc` file (keep a copy of the good one) and move tabs from one dock to another. For instance, editing the file you will find:

```
    (gimp-dock
        (book
            (current-page 0)
            (dockable "gimp-buffer-list"
                (tab-style automatic)
                (aux-info
                    (show-button-bar "true"))))))
```

You can delete the `Buffers` definition and move the definition of other dialogs to it. Make sure the parentheses are balanced.

```
    (gimp-dock
        (book
            (current-page 0)
            (dockable "gimp-symmetry-editor"
                (tab-style automatic))
            (dockable "gimp-gradient-list"
                (tab-style automatic)
                (aux-info
                    (show-button-bar "true")))
            (dockable "gimp-pattern-grid"
                (tab-style automatic)
                (aux-info
                    (show-button-bar "true")))
            (dockable "gimp-brush-list"
                (tab-style automatic)
                (aux-info
                    (show-button-bar "true")))
            (dockable "gimp-palette-list"
                (tab-style automatic)
                (aux-info
                    (show-button-bar "true")))            
            )))
```

If you break something, you can either copy your saved copy over, or erase/rename the broken file and have Gimp recreate one.

Comment: So, you're saying that it should never have gotten into this state?  Or that the devs didn't think of this state, so is not fixable through the UI?

Comment: Possibly a [bug that could be reported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues)... Just giving a workaround.